# React-Native animate one item and rest at the same time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation

I am getting items with flatlist and rendering each of them to animate. I want to animate one and, I want all rest of the items should disappear.. But I cant do it, can anyone show me a example about it?

```
 <FlatList
    numColumns={2}
    initialNumToRender={20}
    contentContainerStyle={{
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    margin: SCREEN_WIDTH/40,
    width: '100%'}}
    data={this.state.news}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => <VideoAnimation item={item} index={index}/>}
    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}/>
```

In VideoAnimation:

```
const pic = {
            margin: SCREEN_WIDTH/35,
            width: this.state.width,
            height: this.state.height,
            opacity: this.state.opacity
        };

        const show ={
            opacity: this.state.opacity
        };

  return (
      <Animated.View style={show}>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.captureAnimation.bind(this)}>
       <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: SCREEN_WIDTH / 30}}> {item.title} </Text>
       <AnimatedImage source={{uri: 'http://' + item.picture_path}} style={pic} resizeMode="contain"/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
            );
```

Capture animation function:

```
captureAnimation(){

        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(this.state.width,{
                toValue: SCREEN_WIDTH/1.2,
                duration: 750
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.height,{
                toValue: SCREEN_HEIGHT/1.2,
                duration: 750
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.opacity,{
                toValue: 0,
                duration: 750
            }),
        ]).start(() => this.showVideo());


    };

showVideo(){
        this.setState({
            video: 1,
            show: false,
            width: new Animated.Value(SCREEN_WIDTH/3),
            height: new Animated.Value(SCREEN_WIDTH/3),
            opacity: new Animated.Value(1)
        })
    }
```

after showVideo called, only pressed item gets animated, How can I animate all other items as well?

Comment: you don't want to overwrite your animations and setState like that. You need to tie your animations to your `Animated` component styles and then call the animations. You also probably shouldn't animate height or width directly, especially in a flatlist. You'll get much better performance animating `scale`

Comment: ok yeah it can be mistake, but do you understand what i mean? I have 20 items, I'm animating 1 item and I also want other 19 items to be animated, how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: you also need to make sure you have an animatable FlatList.

In React Native 0.57.0 you can just use `Animated.FlatList`. Below RN 0.57 you can do this:

```
const AnimatedFlatList = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FlatList)
```

In your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    //you only need this one
    scale: new Animated.Value(0),

  }
}
```

change your `pic` style:

```
const pic = {
  margin: SCREEN_WIDTH/35,
  width: SCREEN_WIDTH/3,
  height: SCREEN_HEIGHT/3,
  transform: [{ scale: this.state.scale }],
  opacity: this.state.scale
};
```

and your `show` style:

```
const show ={
  opacity: this.state.scale
};
```

Since scale starts at `0` the item will have a height of 0. If you animated `scale` to 1 then it will have a width of `SCREEN_WIDTH/3` and a height of `SCREEN_HEIGHT/3`

Now your animation is just:

```
Animated.timing(
  this.state.scale,
  { toValue: 1, duration: 750 }
).start()
```

Now any components with those styles will be animated. If you want these to animate into view then you should probably call the animation in `componentDidMount`

You can also change the values of `this.state.scale` to fit other animations via `interpolation`. For example, if you wanted to hide a component while these animated into view you could make a style:

```
const hide = {
  opacity: this.state.scale.interpolate({ inputRange: [0,1], outputRange: [1,0]})
}
```

Comment: bro i think its not working, its just the same thing Im doing now.. just its scales if im not wrong. 

So look, I want to animate one item and all other items will be animated as well, do you think this example shows it?

Comment: Look again, try to imagine. We get every item with flatlist right? and they are just staying there yeah? So when I press on one item, I want this item to animate, at the same time all other items will animate as well? I dont know maybe its not even possible?

Comment: No you don't get every item with FlatList, they render on demand it is virtualized. Yes you can animate all the items of a FlatList, as I said before the animation is not opionated, it animates whatever you put it on. WIthout seeing more of your implementation it's hard for me to help but what you're trying to accomplish is more than possible

Comment: If you want them rendered out of view then you should be using a scrollview instead

Comment: well, if you think you understand it right, can you show me very simple example with the aim of what I want?

Comment: Ok take a look , hope it will be understandable.

https://snack.expo.io/BJkBiEWKm

Comment: snack doesn't work, I'm guessing `react-native-video` has native code. So you want the FlatList items to be visible when they render, and onClick you want them to do what? Grow to full size?

Comment: yeah snack not working i just wanted to show you full code. Yeah look they will be visible like snapchat discover, and when I press one of them, it will grow to full size and others will fade or disappear or something like that, do you understand now?

Comment: I think maybe its not even possible.. So actually I found a solution, lets say.. I navigate to other screen. First I animate so image gets bigger, then flatlist disappears, and then I navigate to other screen

Comment: here is a *very* basic example: https://snack.expo.io/Hyb9GLbtX I will update my answer with some explanations soon